# Go run config gives error permission for Fleet-based dev environment from Space

Tags: go, jetbrains-fleet, jetbrains-space

I am running a Fleet-based dev environment from Space (cool sentence btw). It's a simple Go program. If I open a terminal in Fleet, I can successfully execute `go run cm/server/main.go`. But when creating a run config, I get a `permission denied (os error 13)` error.

My `run.json` file:

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
       "type": "go",
       "name": "localhost",
       "goExecPath": "cmd/server/main.go",
       "buildParams": [],
    },

    ]
}
```

The error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: the issue is your config file.

It needs to look like this:

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "go",
      "name": "findAverage",
      "goExecPath": "/usr/local/go/bin/go",
      "buildParams": [
        "$PROJECT_DIR$/main.go",
      ],
      "runParams":  ["1", "2", "3"]
    }
  ]
}
```

`goExecPath` is the path to the go executable, and you put your main.go file in `buildParams`.

---

[Source](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/fleet/getting-started-with-go.html#create_run_configuration_for_running_code)